# Concatenate private arrays after OpenMP

Tags: arrays, c, concatenation, openmp

I am using OpenMP to parallelize the code below.

```
int *neighbors = malloc(num_of_neigh * sizeof(int));
int pos = 0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    if(M[n*element+i]==1 && element!=i){
        neighbors[pos] = i;
        pos++;
    }
}
```

Below is the code which works properly. However for a great number of `n`, I have a slower implementation due to the **shared variables** `neighbors` and `pos`.

```
int *neighbors = malloc(num_of_neigh * sizeof(int));
int pos = 0;

#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(8)
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    if(M[n*element+i]==1 && element!=i){
        #pragma omp critical
        {
            neighbors[pos] = i;
            pos++;
        }
    }
}
```

As a result, I decided to use local variables for `neighbors` and `pos` and **concatenate the private variables to a global one** after the calculations. However, I have some troubles with these concatenations.

```
int *neighbors = malloc(num_of_neigh * sizeof(int));
int pos = 0;
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(8)
{
    int *temp_neighbors = malloc(num_of_neigh * sizeof(int));
    int temp_pos = 0;
    #pragma omp for
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(M[n*element+i]==1 && element!=i){
            temp_neighbors[temp_pos] = i;
            temp_pos++;
        }
    }

    // I want here to concatenate the local variables temp_neighbors to the global one neighbors.
}
```

I tried the code below in order to achieve the concatenation, but `neighbors` only takes the last value of the `temp_neighbors`, while the rest elements are 0.

```
#pragma omp critical
{
    memcpy(neighbors+pos, temp_neighbors, num_of_neigh * sizeof(neighbors));
    pos++;
}
```

So, the question is:
**How can I concatenate private variables (and especially arrays) to a global one?**
I searched a lot, but didn't find any proper answer. Thanks in advance and sorry for the big question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The global section should look like the following.

```c
#pragma omp critical
{
    memcpy(neighbors + pos, temp_neighbors, temp_pos * sizeof(int));
    pos += temp_pos;
}
```

`memcpy` copies `temp_pos` elements (`temp_pos * sizeof(int)` bytes) of data to first unused position in `neighbors` (`neighbors + pos`). Then `pos` is increased to be index of  next unused position.

Comment: Wouldn't it be even easier (and more performant) to have a global array from the beginning and just let each thread know which part of that shared array it should use?

Comment: @Paul If we knew how many elements each thread needs before starting the loop, a global array would be definitely easier and faster.